# Sommerfeld Expansion & Chemical Potential

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, chemical-potential

I'm trying to show how the chemical potential depends on the temperature and i'm advised to use the Sommerfeld expansion. I'm using it on the density of charge $ n=\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} \rho(\epsilon)n_Fd\epsilon $, which gives $n=\int^{\mu}_{0} \rho(\epsilon)d\epsilon +\frac{\pi^2}{6}(k_BT)^2\frac{d\rho(\epsilon)}{d\epsilon}|_{E=\mu}$.
After having a hard time trying to insert a term with a $ \mu $ in it, I searched on google and found the following excerpt:
[image]

I don't understand the second paragraph and how it gives the$(\mu-E_F)\rho(\epsilon) $ term.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: It's just $f(x)\approx f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)$, with $x=\mu$ and $a=E_F$.

Comment: *Facepalm* Of course! How did I forget that... Thank you!